# codeigniter 3 php 7.2 count() function not working

Tags: php

I have this function

```
$arr = ($data['rajaongkir']['results']);
for($i=0, $c = count($arr); $i < $c; $i++){
    echo ($data['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]['name']); 
}
```

it was worked for me in PHP 5, but got error in codeigniter 3 (PHP 7.2).
i want this function working good in PHP 7.2, please help me to solve this?
thank you.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include the error?

Comment: It would seem to me that a more straight forward `foreach` would be a better way to do this

Comment: Specially as the `$c = count($arr);` seems totally redundant and badly coded anyway

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` **And show us ALL the error message**

Comment: _And a small aside_ There is nothing `codeigniter` in that code

Comment: What do you mean not working? What is the expected result? What's the error? Please add in more details so people can help.

Comment: the error report is Notice: Undefined index: results in .../file.php on line 37

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in ---/file.php on line 40
Paket

Comment: this function i used to get data as json, and it worked in PHP 5, but i've got different case in PHP 7.2

Answer (score 1):

The only reason you'd start to get an error from `count` after upgrading to PHP 7.2 is that the thing you're trying to count isn't countable.

Based on the code inside the loop, you're expecting `$data['rajaongkir']['results']` to be an array, but if you're getting an error from `count` now, then it isn't.

It's something that counts as 0, because if it was > 0  the loop would execute and you'd also be seeing undefined index notices when you tried to refer to `$data['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]`. I think it's most likely `null` in cases where you get the warning. `count(null)` will return `0`, but [as of PHP 7.2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php#refsect1-function.count-changelog), it generates a warning.

> count() will now yield a warning on invalid countable types passed to the array_or_countable parameter.

`count()` is unnecessary there anyway. You can just use a `foreach` loop instead, and check that your array really is an array before iterating it, because `null` isn't iterable either.

```
if (is_array($arr)) {
    foreach($arr as $result) {
        echo $result['name'];
    }
}
```

That `if (is_array($arr)) {` check will prevent the warning, but *you really need to find out **why** the thing you're expecting to be an array isn't*. You should fix the problem rather than covering it up. Based on a quick google search of "rajaongkir", it looks like that array is a decoded JSON response from a web API, and if there is no `results` key, then there was probably some kind of problem with your request that you should detect and handle in your code.

Comment: still get the same result. this function i used to get data as json,

Comment: The same result? How can you get an error related to count if you aren't using count any more? Seems strange...